# Lagrange multipliers in 4d spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, vectors

I am working through a derivation from [Synge: Relativity the General Theory](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/synge-relativity-general.pdf) (pg 374) regarding phase velocities in a 4D spacetime.

The derivation boils down to minimising the function

$$ u'^2 = 1 + \frac{dx_i dx^i}{(V_jdx^j)^2} \tag{15}$$

subject to the condition,

$$ p_i dx^i = 0\tag{9}$$

$dx^i$ is an infinitesimal displacement on the world line, $V_j$ the 4 velocity of an observer and $p_i$ the 4-momentum of a particle.

Now, Synge states in the subsequent line that minimising the function subject to the condition gives,

$$ dx^i = \alpha V^i +p^i\tag{16}$$

but was this arrived at?

I can understand how to form the Lagrange function from [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Example_1), but cannot arrive at the expression from Synge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "infinitesimal displacement" actually mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the parenthetical statement after Eq.(16): "we omit a multiplier in front of $p^i$ since only the ratios of $dx^i$ are involved in Eq.(15)".

Treat the $dx^i$ as finite variables and apply the Lagrange multiplier technique as usual for a variation of $dx^i$ to obtain 
$$
\frac{dx_i}{(V_jdx^j)^2} - 2\frac{dx_jdx^j}{(V_jdx^j)^3}V_i - \lambda p_i = 0
$$
and from there
$$
dx^i = 2\frac{dx_jdx^j}{V_jdx^j}\;V^i  + \lambda (V_jdx^j)^2 \;p^i
$$
Imposing $p_i dx^i = 0$ gives 
$$
\lambda = - 2\frac{dx_jdx^j}{(V_jdx^j)^3} \frac{p_jV^j}{p_jp^j}
$$
and then
$$
dx^i = \lambda (V_jdx^j)^2 \left( - \frac{p_jp^j}{p_jV^j} V^i + p^i \right)
$$
If only the ratios of $dx^i$ matter, the factor of $\lambda (V_jdx^j)^2$ can be discarded and the result coincides with Eqs.(16) after substitution of Eq.(17).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. I also have a follow up question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305452/derivation-of-a-hamiltonian-in-geometrical-optics if that is also your area? Thanks again!